# find a pair in a STL list where only first element is known

Tags: c++, list, dictionary, stl, queue

assumend I have a (filled) list

```
std::list<std::pair<int,otherobject>> myList;
```

and want to find() the first element within this list, where int has a specific value - how can I do that?

To explain it a bit further:

I want to append these pairs to the list with an int that identifies otherobject but is not unique. The order where these int/otherobject pairs arrive has to be kept.

When an int is found during access to elements of this list the first occurence of that int has to be given back (and removed).

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think I'd use the standard `find_if` algorithm:

```
auto pos = std::find_if(myList.begin(), myList.end(),
                        [value](std::pair<int, otherobject> const &b) { 
                            return b.first == value; 
                        });
```

That gives an iterator to the element with the required value -- from there, you can copy the value, delete the value, etc., just like with any other iterator.

Comment: Even I'd use `std::find_if`. +1.

Comment: "The signature of pred must effectively be bool pred(const T& arg)" 

based on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkwky1wa.aspx

Comment: I'm on VS2013 and the above code(I used pair<string, int> instead) gives me the following cryptic error:
error C2784: 'unknown-type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<std::pair<std::string,int>>>>' C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\algorithm 3157 1 plotutil

Answer (score 1):

According to your need the better option would be to use a multimap.
In you case it would give :

```
std::multimap<int, otherobject> myMultiMap;
```

Then when looking for otherobjects linked to a int ( myInt) you'll do :

```
    std::pair<std::multimap<int, otherobject>::iterator, std::multimap<int, otherobject>::iterator> result = myMultiMap.equal_range(myInt);

    for (std::multimap<int,otherobject>::iterator iter=result.first; iter!=result.second; ++iter)
    {
        std::cout << it->second;
    }
```

This is a STL container so you'll easilly find online documentation.

Comment: In multimap the position of a newly added dataset is not defined, I can't force it to e.g. append it. There is only the possibility to give a _hint_ during insert - but multimap does not need to use this hint.